# Register named instance in ObjectFactory

Tags: structuremap

I try to register named instances in structure map. But my trials are not successful.

What is the correct way?

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
IService bus = CreateInstanceOfServiceBus();
ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg => cfg.For<IServiceBus>()
                                  .AddInstances(x =>x.IsThis(bus)
                                  .Named("foobar"))
                                  .Singleton());
```

But when I try to get the named instance, nothing is found:

```
ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance<IServiceBus>("foobar");
```

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Joachim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply register as follows

```
IServiceBus bus = CreateInstanceOfServiceBus();
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.ForSingletonOf<IServiceBus>().Use(bus).Named("bus"));
```

Now you can resolve the instance either like this

```
ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IServiceBus>("bus");
```

or

```
ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance<IServiceBus>("bus");
```

You are using the **Configure** method which simply adds another configuration to the container. Consider if you will change to **Initialize**, which initializes a new configuration.